# Does IFTTT app drain battery faster in iPhone (and Apple Watch)?

Tags: iphone, battery, power, apple-watch

The IFTTT app sounds interesting with endless possibilities. I have just installed it but skeptical about using it because of the possibility of battery drain. The app has to keep track of every event of the app you associate it with.

So, does the IFTTT app have a noticeable affect in battery consumption or just like any other 'average' background activity?

Answer (score 2):

I use IFTTT on my iPhone X iOS 11.4.

When I check `Settings -> Battery` and look at the last 7 days, IFTTT doesn't even show-up on the list of applications.  That means it's using less than 1% of my battery.

My recommendation to you, if you're thinking of using IFTTT, is to try it with a handful of recipes for a few weeks.  Then check the battery usage and see the impact on battery life.

Now, I'm sure this will change depending on how many recipes you're using and what kind of recipes they are.  IFTTT is just woken-up by iOS at periodic intervals to check for system notifications that something happened.